# java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I am making a custom-sql appication. I made a service builder , created finder column,built and deployed it. Table created successfully. Now I made a ***FinderImpl** class manually and a custom-sql folder with necessary details and rebuilt the services. ***Finder** interface generated successfully. I implemented ***Finder** interface in ***FinderImpl** class, then rebuilt services but ***FinderUtil** not generated. I ignored it as I could easily call ***FinderImpl** class' method directly. I created a custom method inside ***FinderImpl** class and rebuilt the service. I am calling this method inside ***LocalServiceImpl** and calling the method of ***LocalServiceImpl** through ***LocalServiceUtil**. But to my surprise I got the most common error-"**NullPointerException**".I debugged and found that **getService()** method of ***LocalServiceUtil** has value as null. Please tell me how to eradicate this error as I have been stuck throughout the day but could not resolve. So,please help. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Are you extending `BasePersistenceImpl<E>` in your `*FinderImpl`?

Comment: On 2nd build after implementing interface, it should have generated `*FinderUtil`. What traces are you observing in builder?

Comment: I declared the class *FinderImpl as follows:-          public class CustomUser2FinderImpl extends CustomUser2PersistenceImpl implements CustomUser2Finder

Comment: For what entity are you trying to add finder? `User`???

Comment: Entity name is CustomUser2

Comment: Try with this: `public class CustomUser2FinderImpl extends BasePersistenceImpl<CustomUser2> implements CustomUser2Finder` and build service again.

Comment: @Parkash: I tried with your code ,still no effect..

Comment: What problems are you still observing?

Answer (score 2):

I've been having the same issue getting a `NullPointerException` when I add a `EntityFinderImpl` class to my Service Builder.

I've just found that I need to add a Component annotation to my `EntityFinderImpl` class:

```
@Component(
        service = EntityFinder.class
)
public class EntityFinderImpl extends EntityFinderBaseImpl implements EntityFinder {
    public List<Entity> findByDate(Date date) {
        ...
        return dates;
    }
}
```

This appears to occur as EntityLocalServiceBaseImpl class gets a `@Reference` added point ing to the `EntityFinder`, but that reference cannot be satisfied as there is no component to reference.

You can diagnose if this is the issue in a Gogo shell using the command:

```
ds:unsatistied
```

Or optionally:

```
ds:unsatisfied <bundleid>
```

You can also review the components and references that a bundle has using the Gogo command:

```
scr:list <bundleid>
```

Lastly, see also [Liferay's Detecting Unresolved OSGi Components](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-0/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/detecting-unresolved-osgi-components) doc.

Answer (score 0):

you class finder declaration have to be

```
public class CustomUser2FinderImpl extends CustomUser2BaseFinderImpl implements CustomUser2Finder
```

When you build the service there are some properties in build.gradle so if you want to generate the FinderUtil class has to set osgiModule to false.

```
buildService {
    osgiModule = false
}
```

Otherwise if you want to use osgi you can retrive the finder this way

```
@Reference
private volatile CustomUser2Finder customUser2Finder;
```